# How to plot the frequency chart and world cloud from the frequency list created in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, nltk, word-cloud

I have data frame of n-grams frequency which is created by below code. How can create frequency plot and word cloud from the below output.

**Code**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(3,3), analyzer='word')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(dfs[dfs.columns[2]])
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
df =pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
```

**Output**

```
                        frequency
abbott issues deliver     10
abiding govt india        15
ability adapt totally      4
ability case emergencies  35    
ability even client       11
ability get things         6
ability grow kn 1         18
```

Comment: You want a frequency plot representing the n-grams or the words?

Comment: @GregoirePelegrin, yes correct

Comment: @GregoirePelegrin, I want to plot representing n-grams